# How to add google maps to magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to add google maps into my custom module page in magento but the script loaded from google server requires api key. I am able to add this url with the kay hardcoded like:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyApi-123Key" src_type="url" content_type="js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

But I am wondering is there a way to have this key set in the configuration and get it from the config table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find any way to hook into the rendering code of the `head` part of layout configuration although some magento2 plugin approach probably is available but it would be to broad to deal with all assets. Also there is no way to add block (as with `<block ... />` statement) in this section. But magento2 has `head.additional` block where you can create a standard block with template and logic and it will be rendered in the html `<head>` section. The only thing to do is to define it in the `<body>` section of layout xml.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
            <block class="Your\Module\Block\Script" name="googlemaps.api" template="Your_Module::script.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and in phtml file simply put:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<?php echo $this->getApiKey();?>" async defer></script>
```

and create `getApiKey` method in your block class that looks like this:

```
namespace Your\Module\Block

class Script extends Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getApiKey()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('path/to/config');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to add the link to all your pages, you can use

```
Your_Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

with the content

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Your_Module\Block\Script" name="googlemaps.api" template="Your_Module::script.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In your script.phtml file

```
Your_Module/view/frontend/templates/script.phtml
```

add following code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=<?= $block->getApiVersion() ?>&key=<?= $block->getApiKey();?>"></script>
```

In your block class Script.php file

```
Your_Module/Block/Script.php
```

add following code

```
namespace Your_Module\Block

class Script extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getApiKey()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('path/to/config');
    }

    public function getApiVersion()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('path/to/config');
    }
}
```

ApiKey and ApiVersion should be two configuration settings in admin with their own specific 'path/to/config' paths